# Openai Function Calling returns incomplete arguments object "{"

Tags: node.js, typescript, openai-api

It appears that the function calling response is quite unreliable, as it does not return a complete arguments object.
Here is an example of the JSON Schema for a function that I'm trying to get it to call.

```js
export const getCoinPrice: ChatCompletionFunctions = {
  name: "get_coin_price",
  description: "Get the current price for any cryptocurrency",
  parameters: {
    type: "object",
    properties: {
      coin_symbol: {
        type: "string",
        description: "The symbol of the asset to get the price for. Eg: BTC",
      },
    },
    required: ["coin_symbol"],
  },
};
```

This is then passed to the chat request like so:

```js
 const chatRequest: CreateChatCompletionRequest = {
      model: "gpt-3.5-turbo-0613",
      temperature: 0.5,
      n: 1,
      stop: "\n",
      messages: messages,
      function_call: "auto",
      functions: functions,
    };

    const response = await this.openai.createChatCompletion(chatRequest);
```

The Contents of the message response will look like so:

```js
{"role":"user","content":"what is the current price of bitcoin"},{"role":"assistant","content":"","function_call":{"name":"get_coin_price","arguments":"{"}
```

Arguments should be of type object but I couldn't get it to return anything other than "{"

It can't be an issue with how I'm passing it the message since I'm using the types provided by the package:

```js
    input: string,
    chatHistory: ChatCompletionRequestMessage[],
    functions: ChatCompletionFunctions[]
```

I can't seem to find the source of the issue so any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue, i cross referenced to see what similarities we had, and it seems like getting rid of the stop rule works

```json
"function_call": {
                    "name": "get_coin_price",
                    "arguments": "{\n  \"coin_symbol\": \"BTC\"\n}"
                 }
```